# Turn multiple-row MySQL rows into multiple columns and a single row

Tags: mysql

The following MySQL query

```
SELECT
    `FBM_Orders`.`order-id`,
    `FBM_Orders`.`purchase-date`,
    `FBM_Orders`.`buyer-name`,
    `FBM_Orders`.`sku`,
    `IM_INV`.`LOC_ID`,
    `IM_INV`.`QTY_ON_HND`
FROM
    `FBM_Orders`
LEFT JOIN `IM_INV` ON `FBM_Orders`.`sku` = `IM_INV`.`ITEM_NO`
WHERE
    `FBM_Orders`.`quantity-to-ship` > 0
ORDER BY
    `FBM_Orders`.`purchase-date`,
    `IM_INV`.`LOC_ID` ASC;
```

yields

```
| order-id          |  purchase-date          |  buyer-name | sku   |LOC_ID|QTY_ON_HND|
|112-9548231-5585051|2017-09-11T21:34:27+00:00|Zacchary Motz|IE51198|AF    | 2        |
|112-9548231-5585051|2017-09-11T21:34:27+00:00|Zacchary Motz|IE51198|LO    | 1        |
|112-9548231-5585051|2017-09-11T21:34:27+00:00|Zacchary Motz|IE51198|S     | 1        |
|112-9548231-5585051|2017-09-11T21:34:27+00:00|Zacchary Motz|IE51198|SL    | 0        |
```

I have looked around on posts with similar questions but they're all using GROUP_CONCAT and that gets a different result than what I'm looking for. I would like to know how to get the result to be

```
| order-id  | purchase-date  | buyer-name  | sku   | AF_QTY | LO_QTY | S_QTY  | SL_QTY |
|112-95482..|2017-09-11T21...|Zacchary Motz|IE51198|   2    |   1    |   1    |   0    |
```

Thank you

Comment: AF,LO,S & SL are these fixed values or there can be more

Comment: It's those 4 or none on occasion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your desired result set you can use conditional sum of `QTY_ON_HND` based on `LOC_ID`

```
SELECT
    o.`order-id`,
    o.`purchase-date`,
    o.`buyer-name`,
    o.`sku`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN i.`LOC_ID` =  'AF' THEN i.QTY_ON_HND ELSE 0 END) AF_QTY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN i.`LOC_ID` =  'LO' THEN i.QTY_ON_HND ELSE 0 END) LO_QTY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN i.`LOC_ID` =  'S' THEN i.QTY_ON_HND ELSE 0 END) S_QTY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN i.`LOC_ID` =  'SL' THEN i.QTY_ON_HND ELSE 0 END) SL_QTY,
    i.`LOC_ID`,
    i.`QTY_ON_HND`
FROM
    `FBM_Orders` o
LEFT JOIN `IM_INV` i ON o.`sku` = i.`ITEM_NO`
WHERE
    o.`quantity-to-ship` > 0
GROUP BY o.`order-id`,
    o.`purchase-date`,
    o.`buyer-name`,
    o.`sku`
ORDER BY
    o.`purchase-date`
```

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but just checking that this should work when there are multiple order-id's correct?

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: Yes it should work because group by contains the order id column

Comment: Oh durr.. I missed that part. Thanks! I'll give this a try.